# comparator of priorityqueue in java

Tags: java, comparator, priority-queue

Im trying to use the override comparator method of priorityqueue and i want to achieve the following:

i have the current list:

```
RG3

PR1

PR2

RG4

RG1

RG2
```

the RG refers to a regular person and the PR refers to a person with priority, the numbers represent the turns.
what i want is to get a First in first out order except when is a priority person wich will go to the top of the queue in his turn. so in the list i want the following result

```
PR1

PR2

RG1

RG2

RG3

RG4
```

heres what ive done until now:

```
Queue<Ficha> cola = new PriorityQueue<>(6, idComparator);


while (!list.isEmpty()) //this list is the unsorted list.
         {
             aux = list.remove(0);

             cola.add(aux); // adds it to the priority queue

         }

         while(!cola.isEmpty())
         {
             aux = cola.poll();
             System.out.println(aux.getCod_priority()+aux.getTurn()); // this shows me the order of the queue
         }


    }

    public static Comparator<Ficha> idComparator = new Comparator<Ficha>()
    {

        @Override
        public int compare(Ficha f1, Ficha f2) {
            return (int) ((f1.getTurn()+prioridad(f1.getCod_priority())) - (f2.getTurn()+prioridad(f2.getCod_priority())));
       }
    };


    private static long prioridad(String cod_priority) // this method i use it to give the cod_priority a int value to compare 
    {
        if(cod_tipo_ficha=="PR")
        {
            return 10000;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

and when i run it i get the following order:

```
PR1

RG1

RG2

PR2

RG3

RG4
```

i know my problem is in the comparator method but i dont know how to achieve the queue that i want.

i know theres a lot of question related of how to compare but the only answers i see is when you compare strings. and this one i need to compare the priority string and the int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change cod_tipo_ficha=="PR" to

```
if("PR".equals(cod_tipo_ficha)) {
    ...
}
```

Should work

Comment: @amique that's common error. I am doing 5 such bugs per day.